# how to prevent responsive gride in ionic?

Tags: button, ionic-framework

I would like to place 4 buttons in a row. However the buttons go to the next new line when tested on smaller screen devices. I would like to fix 4 buttons in one row and adjust the buttons sizes but not push the button to the next line.... how to do that?

```
    <ion-grid>


    <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-25>

    <!--    <button ion-button type="button" round small>House 1</button> -->

        <button ion-button small round>create</button>  

        </ion-col>

        <ion-col col-25>

    <!--    <button ion-button type="button" round small>House 2</button>  -->

                <button ion-button small round>views</button>

        </ion-col>

        <ion-col col-25>

        <!--<button ion-button type="button" round small>House 3</button> -->

                <button ion-button small round>update</button>

        </ion-col>


        <ion-col col-25>

    <!--    <button ion-button type="button" round small>House 4</button> -->

                <button ion-button small round>delete</button>

        </ion-col>


    </ion-row>




</ion-grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace col-25 with col-md-3 like this,

```
<ion-grid>

    <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-md-3>

    <!--    <button ion-button type="button" round small>House 1</button> -->

        <button ion-button small round>create</button>  

        </ion-col>

        <ion-col col-md-3>

    <!--    <button ion-button type="button" round small>House 2</button>  -->

                <button ion-button small round>views</button>

        </ion-col>

        <ion-col col-md-3>

        <!--<button ion-button type="button" round small>House 3</button> -->

                <button ion-button small round>update</button>

        </ion-col>


        <ion-col col-md-3>

    <!--    <button ion-button type="button" round small>House 4</button> -->

                <button ion-button small round>delete</button>

        </ion-col>


    </ion-row>
```

Hope that helps